WhatApps on a PC Without a Smart Phone?
My mum is 82 and only has a simple mobile phone (pre-smart phones) in the UK.  She uses a laptop.  I want to set up a WhatsApp account for her on the lap top, linked to her phone number.  This way she can view 1000s of videos of her 2 year old grandson in Australia.  Is there a way to do this?

If you define laptop as a Chromebook then possible as certain Chromebooks can run Android and that has WhatsApps support
